# Is it possible to simulated Object.getOwnPropertyNames in IE8

Tags: javascript, oop, internet-explorer-8

Is it possible to simulate `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` in IE8?

I'm trying to get this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DnrU9/7/) to work in IE8.

I believe the only thing left is to make a function simulating `getOwnPropertyNames`.

Of course other solutions to the base problem of extending a JavaScript object with object literals in IE8 is greatly appreciated.

**Updated**: Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DnrU9/9/) which makes use of an external es5 shim script file.

**Conclution**: No, but you can shim Object.keys

Comment: **Conclusion** No, but you can shim Object.keys

Answer (score 10):

No.

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` returns both *enumerable* and *non-enumerable* own properties of an object.  It's not possible to iterate over non-enumerable properties in ECMAScript 3rd Edition implementations, so you can only get those that are enumerable.

It's fairly simple to write a procedure to return enumerable own properties:

```
var arr = [];
for (var k in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) 
        arr.push(k); 
}
```

This is (more or less) the equivalent of [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).  If this isn't sufficient, however, then you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks, It seems that my properties are enumerable as the updated fiddle works.

Comment: @Farmor: then you should probably be using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) instead.